# Checked everything, object won't show up in render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, particles

I've been modelling a donut with the bells and whistles and run into an issue where the icing of the donut is invisible both in the render and in the rendered viewport. I have a situation of having the base donut with these random floating sprinkles (as the icing is not there).

Here's my file on blend exchange:

[image]

I checked that the camera icon was showing like the rest of the objects, checked the layers, the passes etc.

At one point I found an AttributeError in the console talking about "SpaceInfo" and "tree_type" but sadly I could not reproduce the issue to get it to trigger again. I scoured the web to find a similar issue but no one seemed to have what I do, i checked my modifiers on that object to see whether the subsurf was doing something weird but it wasn't, so I leave this up to you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I have attached my file on blend exchange"... but you forgot to paste the provided link in the question text...

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must check the "*Emitter*" box in the *Render* panel of your Particle System settings, otherwise the mesh won't show up, only the particles.

[image]

Comment: Does the AttributeError line in the console get triggered by this setting or was that from something else?

Comment: I don't think this attribute would trigger an error. That must be something else.